# VSTS release XML Transform applicationSettings

Tags: azure-devops, release, t4

I'm trying to make the XML transformation work on a .config file and it works on the  &  sections but not on the  section, it should be: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution

Image capture below from VSTS variables screen and the result in the file generated on the server

[image]

[image]

Can you tell me why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has the issue (can update something like conectionString, but can’t update applicationSettings), I submit a feedback here: [XML variable substitution for applicationSettings](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6134).

On the other hand, you need to check XML variable substitution option for variable transform instead of XML transformation.

Update:

> The fix will be available in upcoming deployment.